# Calculate sum and length of a list simultaneously with foldl and a tuple

Tags: haskell, fold

I've been struggling with foldr for a while now. i want to convert a list of ints to a single tuple that contains the sum of list and number of ints. for example [1,2,3,4] -> (10,4) 
the function i have below iterates through the list fine but only outputs the last element as the x val and 1 as the y val.

```
toTuple xs = let tuple = foldl (\a b -> ((sum1 + b),(len1 + 1))) (0.0,0.0) xs 
              in tuple   
               where sum1 = 0
                     len1 = 0
```

i originally had sum1 and len1 as functions that take in an single int as an input but that didnt' work either so i changed them to variables initailized to 0. however it seems like its setting sum and len to 0 at every element in the list. any suggestions to modify this? thanks!

Comment: Note that you aren't actually using `a` in the function you pass to `foldl`. `sum1` and `len1` are always `0`, because you defined them to be so.

Comment: i originally had them as functions where sum1 a = sum1 + a and len1 = len1+ 1 but i was getting infinite type errors which makes sense sum1 is a function not a variable

Comment: Well that makes sense: if you want to compute the value of `sum1 + a`, then you have to look at the value of `sum1`, which is `sum1 + a`, which brings our total to to `sum1 + a + a`.  Next, you need to compute the value of `sum1` in *that* expression.  Ad infinitum.

Comment: Anyways, there's a function called [sum](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.6/base-4.10.1.0/Prelude.html#v:sum) and another one called [length](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.6/base-4.10.1.0/Prelude.html#v:length) which each do exactly what they say on the tin.

Comment: `((sum1 + b),(len1 + 1))` is equivalent to `(b,1)`, according to the above definitions -- that can not work.

Comment: @helloworld: well writing things like `a = sum1 + a` does not makes any sense since variables in Haskell are *immutable*: you can not reassign them (in fact you can not assign them in the first place, only declare them).

Comment: Why are you by the way constantly talking about `foldr`, but use `foldl` in your code sample?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry, i started initally wrote it with foldr but switched to foldl so i kept mixing the two up - i meant foldl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you haven’t built an intuition for folds yet. You can think of a fold like `foldl combine start input` as starting with some `start` value, then combining that value with each element of the `input` using the `combine` function. The function accepts the current “state” and the next element of the list, and returns the updated state. So you are very close to a working solution:

```
toTuple xs = foldl (\ (sum, len) x -> (sum + x, len + 1)) (0, 0) xs
```

Stepping through an example input like `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, the state `(sum, len)`, usually called an “accumulator”, takes on the following values each time the folding function is called:

```
(0, 0)
(0+1, 0+1)             = (1, 1)
(0+1+2, 0+1+1)         = (3, 2)
(0+1+2+3, 0+1+1+1)     = (6, 3)
(0+1+2+3+4, 0+1+1+1+1) = (10, 4)
```

At no point are we modifying any variables, just calculating the *next* value of the sum and the length by combining the *current* partial sum & length with each element of the list. For a left fold (`foldl`) that’s done from left to right; for a right fold (`foldr`) it’s from right to left, so the order of the parameters (`(sum, len)` and `x`) is reversed:

```
toTuple xs = foldr (\ x (sum, len) -> (sum + x, len + 1)) (0, 0) xs
```

However, for right folds, I find it easier to think of them as replacing all the `:` in a list with a function and replacing the `[]` with a value:

```
foldr f z [1, 2, 3, 4]
foldr f z (1 : (2 : (3 : (4 : []))))
1 `f` (2 `f` (3 `f` (4 `f` z)))
```

Comment: thinking of foldl visually like that is really helpful and clear, thanks for taking the time to explain it like that!

Comment: @helloworld: No problem. Please mark my or Willem Van Onsem’s answer as the accepted answer if you feel it’s adequately answered your question. :)

Answer (score 6):

Well `foldl` has type [**`foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:foldl) with `a` the type of the accumulator (here a 2-tuple), and `b` the type of elements in the list.

But in your *lambda expression* you write

```
\a b -> ((sum1 + b),(len1 + 1))
```

Note that here the variable `b` is an element of the list, and `a` is a tuple. But here you omit the accumulator. You always add `sum1` to `b`, but since `sum1`, is a constant, that is rather useless. The same for `len1`, as a result, you will always obtain a tuple that contains the *last* element of the list as first item, and `1` as second item.

But based on your attempt, I think that you somehow aim to write "imperative" code in Haskell. Now in Haskell all variables are *immutable*, so setting `len1` to `0` (in the `where` clause), will result in the fact that `len1` is always `0`, etc. We do not change the accumulator, in fact `foldr` is a recursive function that each time calls itself with parameters with different values, and at the end returns the parameter we call the "*accumulator*".

We can thus change the attempt to:

```
toTuple = (Fractional s, Fractional n) => [s] -> (s, n)
toTuple = foldl (\(cursum, curlen) b -> (cursum + b, curlen + 1)) (0.0,0.0)
```

So here we each time pattern match the accumulator with `(cursum, curlen)` (containing the "*current*" (thus far) sum and length), and each time we construct a new tuple that contains the "new" current sum (the sum of the old sum and `b`), and the "new" current length (the length incremented with one).

But it it still not very elegant: here the initial tuple has value `(0.0, 0.0)`, but as a result, you tell Haskell that this is a 2-tuple where both elements are `Fractional`s. Although this will probably work given there are no rounding errors, why restrict this to `Fractional`s? If you have a list of `Integer`s for example, we can sum these up without any rounding errors. By using `(0, 0)` as initial tuple, we make the tuple a 2-tuple where both elements have a type that belongs to the `Num` typeclass: so numbers. Note that the two do not *per se* have the same `Num` type, which is less restrictive.

So now we got:

```
toTuple = (Num s, Num n) => [s] -> (s, n)
toTuple = foldl (\(cursum, curlen) b -> (cursum + b, curlen + 1)) (0, 0)
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation! that makes more sense to me now. im coming from java so im still getting used to not defining variables like i did above i guess.

Comment: _Caveat lector_: `foldl` almost always performs worse than its non-lazy sibling `foldl'`. They behave the same, so for didactic purposes you needn't worry about it, but in production code you probably want `foldl'`.